# Maintain Angular $scope on navigation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an Angular app with several controllers. I would like each controller to maintain its state even when the user navigates to another controller and back again. Essentially I want each view to load up just as the user last saw it (unless they navigate away from the app entirely or refresh etc.).

I understand how to share state between controllers using a service but this is not what I want. I could create a new service for every controller or put everything on the `$rootScope` but it seems wrong.

What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: If possible: Include everything required for the controller to restore its state to the URL.

Comment: Using the URL is not practical in this case as I'm dealing with things like partially completed forms and data returned from AJAX calls.

Comment: Why the reluctance to use services?

Comment: @Tamlyn So use a service.

Comment: You could use nesting but It's a bit difficult to know without knowing the relationship between your controllers/states.

Comment: If services are the recommended way then that will do. I was hoping for a more generic solution that would, for instance, save the `$scope` object on leaving a view and reinstate it on re-entering.

Answer (score 1):

I would store any persistent data in the `$cookieStore` and maybe even encapsulate it in a service to avoid remembering what the interface to the cookie actually is. Here's an example:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies'
]);

app.service('ticketService', function ($cookieStore) {
    this.getTicket = function () {
        var ticket = $cookieStore.get('currentTicket');
        // Check server for ticket? (additional business logic)
        return ticket;
    };

    this.setTicket = function (ticket) {
        // Validate correct ticket? (additional business logic) 
        $cookieStore.set('currentTicket', ticket);
    };
});

app.controller('ticketController', function ($scope, ticketService) {
    var defaultTicket = { 
        name: '',
        description: ''
    };

    $scope.ticket = ticketService.getTicket() || defaultTicket;

    $scope.$watch('ticket', function (oldValue, newValue) {
        if (oldValue === newValue) { return; }
        ticketService.setTicket(newValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not really looking to persist between page reloads, only between angular views within the same browser page (we need better words for this stuff!). I realise your solutions does both but I was hoping for a simpler or more generic solution. (+1)

Comment: Aye I see. If session persistence isn't what you need a simple service is probably what you're looking for. If the data comes from multiple sources (servers, cache, other services) wrapping these in one service is probably the best approach. Then just `get` on controller instantiation - `set` on `$scope` modifications